# Таймер обратного отсчета под каждого пользователя свой

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Может кто подскажет как реализовать или есть где то готовое решение. Нужен обратный отсчёт но под каждого пользователя отдельно. Типа я зашёл мне начался отсчёт и скидка на сайте, завтра другой зашёл и у него начался свой отсчет и скидка. И что бы при обновлении страницы время не начиналось сначала. Дано мне там допустим два дня и через два дня таймера нету и скидки тоже.
Заранее благодарю за подсказку.

Comment: Если только фронтенд, то хранить время начала отсчёта таймера в куках или localstorage. От этого и отталкиваться.

Comment: При обновлении или выхода из страницы время не начинает считать сначала?

Comment: Нет, куки имеют срок хранения и ты можешь его задать, а локалстораж, если не ошибаюсь, не имеют срока хранения. Но и то и другое пользователь браузера может явно удалить, например при чистке браузера, или намеренно в панели разработчика

Comment: Если нужно железобетонно - то на сервере в БД

Comment: С локалстораж разобрался. А с куки не юзал. Ща буду искать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно кому то нужен будет код.

```
function contador() {
     var dd = localStorage.getItem("dd");
     var hr = localStorage.getItem("hr");
     var mm = localStorage.getItem("mm");
     var ss = localStorage.getItem("ss");
     if (!dd || !hr || !mm || !ss) {
        dd = "1";
        hr = "23";
        mm = "59";
        ss = "59";
        localStorage.setItem("dd", dd);
        localStorage.setItem("hr", hr);
        localStorage.setItem("mm", mm);
        localStorage.setItem("ss", ss);
     }
     var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (dd == 0 && hr == 0 && mm == 0 && ss == 0) {
           clearInterval(interval);

        }
        ss--;
        if (ss == 0) {
           ss = 59;
           mm--;
           if (mm == 0) {
              mm = 59;
              hr--;
           }
           if (hr == 0) {
              hr = 24;
              dd--;
           }
        }
        if (dd.toString().length < 2) dd = "0" + dd;
        if (hr.toString().length < 2) hr = "0" + hr;
        if (mm.toString().length < 2) mm = "0" + mm;
        if (ss.toString().length < 2) ss = "0" + ss;
        $(".contador").html("<div class='timer-info day'>" + dd + "</div> : <div class='timer-info hora'>" + hr + "</div> : <div class='timer-info minuto'>" + mm + "</div> : <div class='timer-info segundo'>" + ss + "</div>");
        localStorage.setItem("dd", dd);
        localStorage.setItem("hr", hr);
        localStorage.setItem("mm", mm);
        localStorage.setItem("ss", ss);
     }, 1000);
  }
  window.onload = contador;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если только фронтенд, то хранить время начала отсчёта таймера в куках или localstorage. От этого и отталкиваться.